# Hold the output of subprocess.Popen with a arbitrary varible

Tags: python

I'd like to retrieve the output from a shell command

```
In [7]: subprocess.Popen("yum list installed", shell=True)
Out[7]: <subprocess.Popen at 0x7f47bcbf6668>

In [8]: Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
Installed Packages
GeoIP.x86_64                          1.5.0-11.el7                     @anaconda
NetworkManager.x86_64  
....
```

The results are output to the console,

How could I hold the output to a variable saying "installed_tools"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `stdout` and/or `stderr` to [`subprocess.PIPE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.PIPE).

```
import subprocess as sp

proc = sp.Popen("yum list installed", shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)

out = proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
print(out)
```

As [suggested in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355562/hold-the-output-of-subprocess-popen-with-a-arbitrary-varible/52355592?noredirect=1#comment91663902_52355592), it's better to use `Popen.communicate()` in case stderr needs reading and gets blocked. (Thanks UtahJarhead)

```
import subprocess as sp

cp = sp.Popen("yum list installed", shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE).communicate()

out = cp[0].decode('utf-8')
print(out)
```

Comment: Why use `proc.stdout.read()` instead of `proc.communicate()[0]`?

Comment: @Utah Both are OK.

Comment: @iBug, no, they are not both ok -- `proc.stdout.read()` will deadlock if stderr needs to be read first, which will happen if you have a significant volume of errors.

Comment: Thank you two. I forgot about that point.